# Python daemon threads seems not work in background

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-daemon

I took a piece of code from https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Daemon_join_method_threads.php and add three lines expecting it works a daemon that delete any file named 'Tested' . It works at start but if while runnig daemon (I guess it does it) I create a new file from command line (in GNU/linux) using 'touch test' nothing happends. I read about it but should have something that I am doing wrong if really threading daemon works in the background.

```
import threading
import time
import logging
import os
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='(%(threadName)-9s) %(message)s',)

def n():
    logging.debug('Starting')
    logging.debug('Exiting')

def d():
    logging.debug('Starting')
    #  I expected these three following lines keep running in the background and delete any new file named 'Test'

    while True:
        if os.path.isfile('test'):
            os.remove ('test')

    time.sleep(5)
    logging.debug('Exiting')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    t = threading.Thread(name='non-daemon', target=n)
    d = threading.Thread(name='daemon', target=d)
    d.setDaemon(True)

    d.start()
    t.start()
```

Comment: i am guessing the main programs exits.  as you are not joining the threads back into the main thread.. try joining it back to the main thread

Comment: But join wait to all threads joined are finished. I want a thread to run 'forever'. My problem is why the code inside does not work

Comment: can you try moving the sleep function under the while true block?

Comment: Yatish, I solved the problem : d.setDaemon(True) does not work. I replace this instruction with d.setDaemon = True wich works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: I also tried d = threading.Thread(name='daemon', target=d, daemon = True) but does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Daemon threads are killed once the main thread exits (see the docs above [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)):

```
ForceBru:~ forcebru$ cat test.py
import threading
import time

def daemon():
    print('Daemon started')
    i = 0
    while True:
        print('Daemon running:', i)
        i += 1

d = threading.Thread(target=daemon, daemon=True)
d.start()
print('Started daemon!')
time.sleep(0.01)
print('Main thread is exiting. See if the daemon thread exits too')
ForceBru:~ forcebru$ python3 test.py
Daemon started
Daemon running: 0
Daemon running: 1
Daemon running: 2
Daemon running: 3
Started daemon!
Daemon running: 4
Daemon running: 5
Daemon running: 6
Daemon running: 7
Daemon running: 8
Daemon running: 9
Daemon running: 10
Daemon running: 11
<snip>
Daemon running: 1508
Daemon running: 1509
Daemon running: 1510
Main thread is exiting. See if the daemon thread exits too
Fatal Python error: could not acquire lock for <_io.BufferedWriter name='<stdout>'> at interpreter shutdown, possibly due to daemon threads

Thread 0x0000700008819000 (most recent call first):
  File "test.py", line 8 in daemon
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x0000000104ea95c0 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6
ForceBru:~ forcebru$
```

You won't necessarily get the error, but still take a look at what it says:

```
Fatal Python error: could not acquire lock for <_io.BufferedWriter name='<stdout>'> at interpreter shutdown, possibly due to daemon threads
```

So, Python was trying to shut itself down *while a daemon thread was still running*. So, your script actually exits because, as per the docs:

> ...the entire Python program *exits* when only daemon threads are left